# Target word following Keyword

Tags: regex, vim

I am learning how to make vim syntax files and this is what I have so far:

```
runtime! syntax/lua.vim
syntax keyword tiKeyword class mixin extends alias abstract

highlight link tiKeyword Keyword
```

As you can see it is an extension of the Lua language that supports syntax used in my framework.

What I am struggling to do is target a word following the tiKeyword

I want `class <WORD>` or `mixin <WORD>` (for each keyword) to be highlighted so that the class/mixin is a keyword and the `<WORD>` is a Statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
syn keyword tiKeyword  class mixin nextgroup=tiIdent skipwhite
syn match   tiIdent    "\%(\%(class\s\|mixin\s\)\s*\)\@<=\h\%(\w\|\.\)*" contained

highlight link tiKeyword   Keyword
highlight link tiIdent     Identifier
```

We first create `tiKeyword` which is a very simple `syntax keyword` which highlights `class` and `mixin`. The "magic" here is using the [`nextgroup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn%2dnextgroup) argument, which tells Vim to try those syntax groups for a match *after* this one.

The `itIndent` syntax matches the keywords followed by the identifier. I actually lifted this from the Python syntax file ;-)